# Changing values (with apply) in one column of pandas dataframe depending on particular values in other column in this dataframe with mask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-apply

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [69, 77, 88],
                   'col2': ['barf;', 'barf;', 'barfoo']})
print(df, '\n')

   col1    col2
0    69   barf;
1    77   barf;
2    88  barfoo
```

Also i have selection function:

```
def selection_func(string):
    '''
    Function returns a, if string is 'barf;'
    '''
    if string == 'barf;':
        return 'a'
    else:
        return string
```

So I need to change particular values (not all) in col2 with condition based on col1:

```
condition = (df['col1'] == 69) | (df['col1'] == 88)
```

Desired output:

```
   col1    col2
0    69       a
1    77   barf;
2    88  barfoo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution while was writing the question:

```
df.loc[condition, 'col2'] = df.loc[condition, 'col2'].apply(func)
print(df, '\n')

   col1    col2
0    69       a
1    77   barf;
2    88  barfoo
```

Comment: You can also use `df.loc[condition, "col2"] = df.loc[condition,"col2"].mask(df["col2"].eq("barf;"),"a")` without the need to define a function.

Comment: In real project i need to use function, because there're more complex operations (using re.sub() - the regex-pattern replacment). But in this particular case your solution is more efficient, i think. Thank you!